# k-means exception on EMR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This file system object does not support access to the request path

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, amazon-emr, emr

I'm trying to run k-means algorythm from mahout on EMR. The input vectorized data is located at S3.
My command:

```
elastic-mapreduce --jar s3://mybucket/dir/mahout-examples-0.8-SNAPSHOT-job.jar --main-class org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver --arg kmeans --arg -i --arg s3://mybucket/dir/normalized-bigram/tfidf-vectors --arg -c --arg /dir/kmeans-centroids --arg -o --arg /dir/kmeans-clusters --arg -cd --arg 1.0 --arg -k --arg 20 --arg -x --arg 20 --arg -cl --arg -dm --arg org.apache.mahout.common.distance.SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure -j $JOBID --step-name "kmeans-euclidean-distance-measure"
```

Exception I've got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This file system object (hdfs://10.229.34.19:9000) does not support access to the request path 's3://hdp.wtest/wiki/normalized-bigram/tfidf-vectors' You possibly called FileSystem.get(conf) when you should have called FileSystem.get(uri, conf) to obtain a file system supporting your path.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:513)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.RandomSeedGenerator.buildRandom(RandomSeedGenerator.java:71)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.main(KMeansDriver.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:187)
```

What is wrong with my command?

Comment: Did you try what it said in the exception - calling FileSystem.get(uri, conf)?

Comment: Are you sure that the credentials you're using for the elastic-mapreduce program are able to access that S3 bucket?

Comment: @smcg in org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.RandomSeedGenerator.buildRandom method FileSystem.get(uri, conf) is used... I've cheked.

Comment: @JoeK Yes. I've used the same elastic-mapreduce scrip with the same credentials to run vectorizing before...

Comment: did you try s3n:// instead of s3://?